# Open3 and stopped process

Tags: ruby

What's the proper way to check if the process opened with `Open3::popen3` has stopped? I'm piping a huge file that has an error to a process and need to stop as soon as possible preferably with minimal consumption of resources per loop iteration. The programs are essentially something like this

```
# launcher.rb
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ruby', 'consumer.rb') do |i, o, e, w|
  5.times do |n|
    i.puts(n)
    puts "line #{n}"
  end
  puts "Errors: #{e.read}"
end 

# consumer.rb
i = 0
ARGF.each_line do |line|
  if i == 2
    $stderr.write('error')
    exit(1)
  end
  i+=1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`popen3` returns an array, which fourth element is a thread object:

```
prc = Open3.popen3('sleep 10')
=> [#<IO:fd 10>, #<IO:fd 12>, #<IO:fd 14>, #<Thread:0x007f84b49c8480 sleep>]
```

As you can see the Thread itself shows the status, after 10 seconds it will be:

```
=> [#<IO:fd 16>, #<IO:fd 18>, #<IO:fd 20>, #<Thread:0x007f84b437d120 dead>]
```

So to check the process status, you need to investigate `thread.status`, which is `run` or `sleep` if the process is running, and `false` or `nil` if the process finished (false) or died (nil):

```
prc = Open3.popen3('sleep 10')
=> [#<IO:fd 10>, #<IO:fd 12>, #<IO:fd 14>, #<Thread:0x007f84b49c8480 sleep>]
prc[3].status
=> "sleep"
```

after few seconds:

```
prc[3].status
=> false
```